# faye-websocket holding until block finishes

Tags: ruby, multithreading, websocket, eventmachine

When I send messages via a faye-websocket server as middleware, I find the message doesn't send until after the block finishes.

Here's a few examples I've tried:

### No threading

```rb
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'json'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

module SocketTest
  class Websocket

    def initialize(app)
      @app     = app
    end

    def long_function()
      sleep 20
      "foo"
    end    

    def call(env)
      EM.run {
        if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
          ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: 15 })
          ws.on :open do |event|
            response = {
              :responseCode => 100,
              :message => "Connection opened"
            }
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            ws.send(response.to_json)
          end

          ws.on :message do |event|
            response = {
              :responseCode => 100,
              :message => "Received request, running slow function"
            }
            ws.send(response.to_json)
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            long_function_result = long_function()
            response = {
              :responseCode => 200,
              :message => "Long function ran, result is #{long_function_result}"
            }
            ws.send(response.to_json)
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            ws.close()
          end
          ws.on :close do |event|
            $logger.info "< CLOSE"
            ws = nil
          end

          # Return async Rack response
          ws.rack_response

        else
          @app.call(env)
        end
      }
    end    
  end
end
```

**Chrome output**

```
5:25:09pm   WebSocket Connection Established
5:25:09pm   {"request":"test"}
5:25:09pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Connection opened"}
5:25:30pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Received request, running slow function"}
5:25:30pm   {"responseCode":200,"message":"Long function ran, result is foo"}
5:25:30pm   Connection Close Frame
5:25:30pm   Connection Close Frame
```

**Console output**

```
I, [2020-01-15T17:25:10.006006 #25394]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Connection opened"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:25:10.024170 #25394]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Received request, running slow function"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:25:30.034885 #25394]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":200,"message":"Long function ran, result is foo"}I, [2020-01-15T06:25:30.189606 #25394]  INFO -- : < CLOSE
```

As we can see above, the logger output is is immediate (17:25:09) for "Received request, running slow function", however the additional 20 seconds are taken for the response to be sent to the client. I've noticed the same thing with PING/PONG messages - nothing comes from the WebSocket server until the blocking `sleep` finishes.

I've also tried a modified version like this:

### Threading off

```
# Just the call function, all other parts are the same
    def call(env)
      EM.run {
        if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
          ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: 15 })
          ws.on :open do |event|
            response = {
              :responseCode => 100,
              :message => "Connection opened"
            }
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            ws.send(response.to_json)
          end

          ws.on :message do |event|
            response = {
              :responseCode => 100,
              :message => "Received request, running slow function"
            }
            ws.send(response.to_json)
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            long_function = Thread.new { long_function() }
            until (long_function.alive? == false) do
              response = {
                :responseCode => 100,
                :message => "Waiting for long function to complete"
              }
              ws.send(response.to_json)
              $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
              sleep 5

            end
            response = {
              :responseCode => 200,
              :message => "Long function ran, result is #{long_function.value}"
            }
            ws.send(response.to_json)
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            ws.close()
          end
          ws.on :close do |event|
            $logger.info "< CLOSE"
            ws = nil
          end

          # Return async Rack response
          ws.rack_response

        else
          @app.call(env)
        end
      }
    end
```

**Chrome output**

```
5:34:33pm   WebSocket Connection Established
5:34:33pm   {"request":"test"}
5:34:33pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Connection opened"}
5:34:53pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Received request, running slow function"}
5:34:53pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
5:34:53pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
5:34:53pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
5:34:53pm   {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
5:34:53pm   {"responseCode":200,"message":"Long function ran, result is foo"}
5:34:53pm   Connection Close Frame
5:34:53pm   Connection Close Frame
```

**Console output**

```
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:33.473295 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Connection opened"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:33.489433 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Received request, running slow function"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:33.489638 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:38.490995 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:43.491927 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:48.497281 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":100,"message":"Waiting for long function to complete"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:53.499446 #25729]  INFO -- : < {"responseCode":200,"message":"Long function ran, result is foo"}
I, [2020-01-15T17:34:53.632997 #25729]  INFO -- : < CLOSE
```

The result is the same again, although the `$logger` object continues to operate whilst waiting for the thread result (indicating to me we are no longer blocking), it appears the WebSocket is still holding and waiting for its buffer. How can I force this buffer out?

Comment: I am not 100% certain on this, but I wonder if the websocket commands you enter are just being queued until the next tick, and you are blocking the processing of the tick via the sleep. Why do you need these `sleep` calls? There might be a better (async-friendly) way to do it such as [add_timer](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine.add_timer).

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner . At this stage a number of things are being fired off, and a database check happens in a loop. The sleep helps it ensure it's not querying multiple times a second. I mostly write node now, so that does look nicer, thanks I'll give it a try!

Comment: Thanks again @maxpleaner! I've spent a couple of days working with add_timer, and while it's not as robust as async/await in JS it definitely does the job. I've posted an answer with a full code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [add_timer](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine.add_timer) EventMachine function that @max_pleaner suggested I was able to build a working version of the code with internal callbacks to the function to create a loop:

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'json'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

module SocketTest
  class Websocket

    def initialize(app)
      @app     = app
    end

    def call(env)
      EM.run {
        if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
          ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env, nil, {ping: 15 })
          ws.on :open do |event|
            response = {
              :responseCode => 100,
              :message => "Connection opened"
            }
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            ws.send(response.to_json)
          end

          ws.on :message do |event|
            response = {
              :responseCode => 100,
              :message => "Received request, running slow function"
            }
            ws.send(response.to_json)
            $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
            total_runs = 4
            def long_function(ws, count, total_runs)
              if count > total_runs then
                # Error out
                puts "Reached full count, exiting"
                ws.close()
                return
              end
              # Logic here
              if count == 3 then
                response = {
                  :responseCode => 200,
                  :message => "Long function ran"
                }
                ws.send(response.to_json)
                $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
                ws.close()
              else
                response = {
                  :responseCode => 100,
                  :message => "Waiting for long function to complete"
                }
                ws.send(response.to_json)
                $logger.info "< #{response.to_json}"
                EventMachine.add_timer(5) {
                  long_function(ws, count + 1, total_runs)
                }
              end
            end
            long_function(ws, 1, total_runs)
          end
          ws.on :close do |event|
            $logger.info "< CLOSE"
            ws = nil
          end

          # Return async Rack response
          ws.rack_response

        else
          @app.call(env)
        end
      }
    end    
  end
end
```